# Check the progress of Data Import/Restore MySQL in Windows

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, progress, mysqlimport

I am new to MySQL. I have a decent machine and have been importing a 16gb .sql database since yesterday. The progress bar doesn't show anything but it does say **Import is running...**. I have searched everywhere and there is no clear solution to know the progress of the import process in **Windows.**

I have tried:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

and

```
SHOW DATABASES
```

but it doesnt help me indicate an ETA or I don't know what im looking at.

I am running on MySQL workbench 6.3.7. Will you guys be able to help me?

Answer (score 3):

I have also been looking for something to tell me the progress of my import.
Assuming that you are using MySQL Workbench then unfortunately the import status seems to not show anything if you tried to import via `Server > Data Import`. The only suggestion I would give is to monitor the status from `Server > Status`; there you can see CPU usage plus other info.

Also depending on your dump you can try `File > Run SQL Script ...` this will give a progress bar.

My Env

OS: Windows 10

RAM: 16GB

MySQL: 5.7.10

Answer (score 3):

This has been an issue for Mac since 2014 and has affected me today using Ubuntu 17.10.

So disregard this screen, it is useless.

You're thinking along the right lines with `processlist`.

Execute the following command to show running processes:

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST`

If your import is still running, you will expect to see at least one row (process) with a `STATE` of `update`, `COMMAND` of `query`, and the `INFO` column will list the SQL query currently being executed by that process.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's this bug with the workbench that will cause the status bar to not move until the import is complete:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54370

MySQL Workbench shows at least a log for the file it is importing at the moment if you use their import tool (Administration > Import Data) ***BUT*** (and it's a huge but) if you leave the "import progress" screen and try to go back to it later, you won't be able to do it (if it's not a bug, it is at least a big usability problem).

So if you, accidentally or on purpose, leave the progress screen your only option is the one in @8bitjunkie's answer:

Run this query `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` and check whether there's still an update going on.